# Differentiability of two variable function with two possibilities

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

There is a another question which is exactly similar to my question in this website, but I think I am still confused about that too, I couldn't get it. I would be very very very thankful if someone gave a detailed answer to this question such that I can master the method of this sort of problems

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y)\neq 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I need to show that the function is not differentiable in the origin.
I found showed that the directional derivatives exist. But I dont know what to do now. Please help. I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but this is how I think about it:

If $f$ was differentiable, then you would have $df(x;h) = Df(x)h$ for all $h$, where $df(x;h)$ is the directional derivative in the direction $h$ at the point $h$ and $Df(x)$ is the derivative of $f$.

In particular, the function $h \mapsto df(x;h)$ must be linear in $h$ (if $f$ is differentiable at $x$).

Just by definition of the directional derivative, we have $df(x;\lambda h) = \lambda df(x;h)$, so the only way that it can fail to be linear (assuming it exists, of course) is additivity, that is, we can find some $h_1,h_2$ such that $df(x;h_1+h_2) \neq df(x;h_1)+df(x,h_2)$.

In the above, a straightforward computation shows that $df((0,0), (1,0)) = df((0,0),(0,1)) = 0$, but $df((0,0),(1,1)) = {1 \over 2}$.

I just guessed the $h_1,h_2$ for this $f$ from the formula
$df((0,0),h) = { h_1 h_2^2 \over h_1^2+h_2^2}$ ($h \neq 0$, of course).

In many cases, the approach is similar to above, just guess and verify.

**Addendum**: The above approach is one way of showing non-differentiability, however, there are functions for which the directional derivative exists and is linear but the original function is not differentiable.

For example, let $S = \{ (t \cos \theta, t \sin \theta) | \theta \in (0, 2 \pi], 0 \le t \le \theta \}$, and $f((x,y)) = 1_S((x,y))$. Then $df((0,0), h) = 0$ for all $h$ (and so is linear), but the function $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to ask some questions. So the method is that the directional derivatives exist, but they are not linear at $0$, therefore the function is not differentiable at that specific point?

Comment: Yes, because it it was differentiable then the directional derivative would be additive (in directions) at that point. (Note that it is possible that the directional derivatives exist and are linear in $h$ but that the function is still not differentiable, so this is just one approach.)

Comment: I added a note to this effect, but don't let it confuse you. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't misleading.